# How to retrieve intent extra from a specific intent when two intents lead to the same activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 Activities A and B. A navigates and passes extras to B and using intent x.
 **i.e (A -> B)**
B contains a fragment(Bfragment) that passes data to B using an interface.
I use an intent y to get navigate from (Bfragment) to B. 
**i.e ((Bfragment)->B)**
B retrieves extras from the intent x.
On navigating form Bfragment, B tries to retrieve extras from intent y that are supposed to be retrieved from intent x.

How can I ensure that I don't retrieve extras from intent y but intent x in Activity B.

**Activity A.**

```
Intent x  = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
x.putExtra("CMAKE", "TOYOTA");
startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity B.**

```
String cmake=getIntent.getStringExtra("CMAKE");
```

**Fragment B.**

```
Intent y = new Intent(getContext(),B.class);
startActivity(y)
```

Expected:
in B after navigating from BFragment, String cmake should be "TOYOTA" retreived from intent x

Actual:
String cmake is null as it tries to retrieve it from intent y (from BFragment)

Comment: just use some custom String id of your own then use switch condition to determine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Add action to differentiate

You can add action to differentiate the different intents

> For intent x

```
Intent x = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
x.setAction("fromActivity");
```

> For intent y

```
Intent y = new Intent(getContext(),B.class);
y.setAction("fromFragment");
```

### How to differentiate?

```
String action = getIntent().getAction();
  if(action.equals("fromActivity"))
   {
      // your logic
   }
   else if(action.equals("fromFragment")){
      // your logic
   }
   else{
      // your logic
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just check for intent having mentioned extra or not like as below:

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("CMAKE")){
  String cmake=getIntent().getStringExtra("CMAKE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity A.

```
Intent x  = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
x.putExtra("CMAKE", "TOYOTA");
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity B.

```
String cmake=getIntent.getStringExtra("CMAKE");
```

Activity B --> Bfragment (fragment transtition function)

```
Bfragment fragment = new Bfragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("key", cmake);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
```

Fragment B.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mdata = getArguments().getString("key");
    }
```

In intent call on fragment

```
Intent y = new Intent(getContext(),B.class);
y.putExtra("CMAKE", mdata);
    startActivity(y)
```